# JQuery Boostrap append row every 2 iterations but columns are ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using JQuery 3 and Bootstrap 3. I'm trying to add dynamically `row` and `col` but I don't understand my error.

Every 2 iterations I want to add `<div class="row"></div>` in my dom and in this row I want to add 2 columns.

I'd like to get this HTML :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
</div>
```

But the current result what I get is :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
  </div>
```

I don't understand why some col are ignored. Here is my javascript code :

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  let row = $("<div>", {"class": "row"});

  if (i % 2) {
    $('.container').append(row);
  }

  let col = '<div class="col-xs-6">test</div>';
  row.append(col);
}
```

And my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gkn4vmx8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
let row=null;
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

  if (i % 2) {
    row= $("<div>", {"class": "row"});
    $('.container').append(row);
  }

  let col = '<div class="col-xs-6">test</div>';
  row.append(col);
}
```

Comment: because you initialize row every time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  let row = $("<div>", {"class": "row"});
 let col = '<div class="col-xs-6">test</div>';
  if (i % 2) {
    $('.container').append(row);
    row.append(col);
  }


  row.append(col);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinitialize the row every 2 loops not every time so you can append on the same row to childs

```js
let row;
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  

  if (i % 2) {
   row= $("<div>", {"class": "row"});
    $('.container').append(row);
  }

  let col = '<div class="col-xs-6">test</div>';
  row.append(col);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```